# Recovering data from a corrupted disk

Tags: data-recovery

I use an external harddisk to backup my data (it had 3 partitions). Last week when I plugged it in, the OS (Win 7) hung up and I had to force re-boot the machine.

When I turned it back on, the system just did not detect the hard-disk. It was last Sunday and I had to give up after sometime. Now I return back next Sunday (today) and when I plug it back-in to the machine, the OS detects the disk as well as all the 3 partitions on it. But it says all 3 are unformatted and I cant access any of them.

Is there any way to recover data from the 3 partitions (I tried PC File Recovery and Recuva from PiriForm but neither detected these partitions).

Answer (score 1):

At first please be very careful if you really need the data on the disk. It is very ease to produce more damage on the disk using recovery tools. Consider asking a professional if the disk contains importing data. Also consider generating a raw disk image before trying more data recovery tools. An easy way to generate a raw disk image is to use a Linux boot CD.

I've made good experiences with **[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org)**, **[Partition Find and Mount](http://findandmount.com/)**, **Smart Partition Recovery** and **[DiskGenius](http://www.diskgenius.net/)** for checking and recovering partitions. You might find all these tools and more on the [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/).

Another way is to use Linux to try to revover your disk.

Comment: I have used test disk successfully to recover from a laptop and a micro sd card. It is pretty simple to use for basic cases like partition table lost etc..

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use Windows Scandisk on the drive, to see if that fixes it.

If not, I found that GetDataBack-NTFS was good for a few drives people have given me.

Comment: scandisk won't work on raw disk